# Searching within what seems to be an array of arrays in Perl (web sockets)

Tags: arrays, perl

I am writing some code that tries to make sure a new web socket connection has a specific cookie

Here is an excerpt of the connection details I am receiving at the server, which I printed using `print Dumper($handshake->req->cookies);`

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'pairs' => [
                          [
                            'ZMSESSID',
                            'e63n6uk59entuvoed1o76u1hm6'
                          ]
                        ]
           }, 'Protocol::WebSocket::Cookie' );
```

I now need to search inside the "pairs" array of arrays to see if a cookie called 'ZMSESSID' exists. It may or may not exist, and there may be other cookies.

What is the right way to do this?

I tried:

```
if ($handshake->req->cookies->pairs)
{

     my @foo = $handshake->req->cookies->pairs;
     my $match =  grep { $_->[0] eq 'ZMSESSID'} @foo ;
     print "$match\n";
}
```

But that always prints 0, not 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a blessed hashref containing an aray with 1 single element of an array with 2 elements.

so to search you could do ..

```
foreach my $c ( @{ $_->{pairs}[0]} )
{
  print "Match\n" if $c eq 'ZMSESSID';
}
```

although since you have an instance of a WebSocket::Cookie::Request you could use the methods and attributes associated with it as described at http://search.cpan.org/~vti/Protocol-WebSocket-0.19/lib/Protocol/WebSocket/Cookie/Request.pm

Also try `perldoc Protocol::WebSocket::Cookie::Request` from a command shell.

you can access the methods of the object instance (blessed hashref) and access the attributes described in the docs.
$handshake->req->cookies->name

Comment: Peter, sorry I'm sort of a beginner. I have a couple of followups: I tried your last example first:  if ($handshake->req->cookies->ZMSESSID) - that says "Can't locate object method "ZMSESSID" via package "Protocol::WebSocket::Cookie". In your first example, you are using $_ ==> do I need to map it to $handshake->req?

Comment: So I've made some progress with the for loop, but can't seem to figure out how to handle the case where a cookie is present vs. not. My code is at http://pastebin.com/4CbdE5BE --> the "if defined" comes up with "Not an ARRAY reference" when the cookie field actually exists. I was trying to handle the case where it doesn't crash when there are no cookies but ended up messing up the reverse case. How do I handle both?

Comment: What a pain in the butt. It looks like if the cookie list is empty, $handshake->req->cookies is an empty array while if it has cookies, its a hash ref. So  I finally solved it by doing this:   if (UNIVERSAL::isa( $handshake->req->cookies, "HASH" )) (then do your stuff)